# Creation of files with specified file size in python

Tags: python, linux

I have a random file - words.txt which contains below words. Using the below words I need to generate 1 kb, 10 kb, 100 kb and 1 mb files in python in linux. Since am extremely new to Python, can somebody help ?

```
aardvark
aardwolf
aaron
aback
abacus
abaft
abalone
abandon
abandoned
abandonment
abandons
abase
abased
abasement
abash
```

With help of some scripts around web, I have written a small code as below:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python

def generate_file():
fname='/tmp/1.txt'
word_cnt=int(random.random()*10)
rnd_str = ' '
newline_str=''
for wrd in range(1,word_cnt):
    idx = random.randint(1,len(wordlist)-1)
    #print idx
    if ( len( newline_str) > 40 ) :
       newline_str=''
       rnd_str = rnd_str + '\n'
    newline_str = newline_str + ' ' + wordlist[idx]
    rnd_str = rnd_str + ' ' + wordlist[idx]
text_file = open(fname, "w")
text_file.write(rnd_str)
text_file.close()

wordfile = "wordsrange.txt"
wlf = open(wordfile,"r")
wordlist=wlf.read().splitlines()
wlf.close()

generate_file()
```

But am not sure how I can generate 1 kb, 10 kb, 100 kb and 1 mb files, need some help on the same.

Comment: What have you got so far? Have you got code for creating a file and just need to figure out how to get it to the correct size? Or are you starting from nothing?

Comment: So the problem is finding a combination of words that adds up to exactly 1024 bytes?

Comment: @Rawing I doubt that but it would make the question more interesting ☺

Comment: Yeah needed to prepare files with 1kb, 10 kb, 100 kb and 1 mb files with a random text file, please see my update on the question

Comment: Yeah I need to figure out on how to get the file to correct size as expected

Comment: one character (ASCII) is one byte. For a file with 1024 bytes you need 1023 characters (every file ends with a EOF byte). Don't forget: `\n` is a byte too.

Comment: Any help will be greatly appreciated !! Thanks